# Deleting a block of lines starting from a specific word until the next similar block (the next similar "section header")

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file containing the following informations:

```
     gene            3025..3855
                     /gene="Sp34_10000100"
                     /ID="Sp34_10000100"
     CDS             join(3025..3106,3722..3855)
                     /gene="Sp34_10000100"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /ID="Sp34_10000100.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000100.t1.cds2"
     mRNA            3025..3855
                     /ID="Sp34_10000100.t1"
                     /gene="Sp34_10000100"
     gene            12640..13470
                     /gene="Sp34_10000200"
                     /ID="Sp34_10000200"
     CDS             join(12640..12721,13337..13470)
                     /gene="Sp34_10000200"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /ID="Sp34_10000200.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000200.t1.cds2"
     mRNA            12640..13470
                     /ID="Sp34_10000200.t1"
                     /gene="Sp34_10000200"
     gene            15959..20678
                     /gene="Sp34_10000300"
                     /ID="Sp34_10000300"
     CDS             join(15959..16080,16268..16367,18913..19116,20469..20524,20582..20678)
                     /gene="Sp34_10000300"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /ID="Sp34_10000300.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds2,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds3,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds4,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds5"
     mRNA            15959..20678
                     /ID="Sp34_10000300.t1"
                     /gene="Sp34_10000300"
     gene            22255..23085
                     /gene="Sp34_10000400"
                     /ID="Sp34_10000400"
```

I want to delete all the **gene** sections but **CDS** and **mRNA** information should be there. The output should be like this:

```
     CDS             join(3025..3106,3722..3855)
                     /gene="Sp34_10000100"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /ID="Sp34_10000100.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000100.t1.cds2"
     mRNA            3025..3855
                     /ID="Sp34_10000100.t1"
                     /gene="Sp34_10000100"
     CDS             join(12640..12721,13337..13470)
                     /gene="Sp34_10000200"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /ID="Sp34_10000200.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000200.t1.cds2"
     mRNA            12640..13470
                     /ID="Sp34_10000200.t1"
                     /gene="Sp34_10000200"
     CDS             join(15959..16080,16268..16367,18913..19116,20469..20524,20582..20678)
                     /gene="Sp34_10000300"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /ID="Sp34_10000300.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds2,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds3,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds4,Sp34_10000300.t1.cds5"
     mRNA            15959..20678
                     /ID="Sp34_10000300.t1"
                     /gene="Sp34_10000300"
```

Please give me any suggestion how to do this.

Comment: It seems you have a couple of text processing tasks to do with those files. I suggest to not just ask questions and try the answers, but understand them and learn to help yourself. Then you only need to ask if you don't succeed with your own solution. By posting your own attempts we can help you best. Thanks.

Comment: Ya, you are right. But the thing is I am new with this kind of thigns. I am also learning by myself. But I want to see how people solve this. it will help me to learn as well I think. Thanks for your valuable suggestion

Comment: If all gene sections end in a `/ID="` line, `sed '/^ *gene/,/\/ID="/d'` might be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk is usually easier to read and understand:

Here is a simple program that writes by default, and toggle a "wewrite" to "0" (= off, we will not write) when it sees a line where the first word is "gene", and put it back on when he sees a line where the first word is "CDS" or "mRNA" :

```
awk '
  BEGIN                               { weprint=1 }

  ( $1 == "gene" )                    { weprint=0 }
  ( $1 == "CDS" ) || ( $1 == "mRNA" ) { weprint=1 }
  ( weprint == 1)                     { print $0 ;}

  '  file_to_read
```

BEGIN is done before any lines are read.

The other `( test ) { action if test successful }` are parsed for each line of input (... unless an action contains `next`, which then would ignore the rest of those and instead would go fetch the next line of input)

This will only print sections "CDS" and "mRNA" and not "gene"

This could be "golfed" (for example, the default action for a successfull 'test' is to print $0, so you could have just `( weprint == 1)` as the last line, but it would be less clear to grasp, imo...)

Comment: @masum-billah : does this work for you? I just wrote it and didn't test it (can't test at the moment, I can just write from memory)

Comment: Yes, it worked very nicely and was pretty easy to understand by me. I am laughing now why didn"t I get the idea to use this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
sed -e '
   /^ *gene /!b   # print non-gene block begin lines
   :a  
   $d; N          # do-while loop accumulates lines for gene block
   s/\n *\///;ta
   D              # clip the gene block
' yourfile
```

---

You need to realize that the `sed` model is to read a file on a per-line
 basis, and `sed` command in the `-e` section is applied in sequence on the
 line as it get's transformed unless there are `branching` instructions
 involved. And a basic syntax of `sed` is `address command` where command can
 be any valid `sed` command and `address` can be either of these: `linenum`,
 `$` (= last line), `regex`, `range of addresses`, and finally nothing meaning this gets
 applied to ALL lines. Note that lines are stored in a register called the `pattern space`.

So with that basic stuff out of the way, we go to the actual `sed` `-e` code
 at hand:
`b` => branch to the end of sed code and print the pattern space. This means we keep printing any line that does NOT (the `!` after the address pattern) have the string `gene` as it's first field.

When we finally hit the `gene` in the first field line, we set up a do-while loop (`:a` sets a mark to be jumped to) to keep accumulating the lines into the pattern space register (`N` appends the next line; `s` command removes `\n *\/`, which is the line break, followed by spaces and a `/`) till the time either of the 2 conditions are not met, viz., either we hit the eof => we delete it (`$d` => delete pattern space if we are at the last line) since this a gene block which appeared towards the eof and must go.

OR we hit the beginning of next block: if `s` could find and remove the said pattern, the `t` will jump to `:a`, otherwise (a new block, so the pattern was not found), we continue. Now the pattern space holds the whole of the gene block and the first line of the next block. We promptly delete the gene block and with the beginning of the next block we go to the top of sed code (that's what the `D` command does).

Comment: Sorry can you please bit explain it to me. I am a new learner

Comment: Thanks Rakesh Sharma it worked well and thanks again for making the commands so clear to me

Answer (score 1):

I can't resist to give a *perl* answer when we have *sed* and *awk* answer!

```
# make perl complain when it should
use strict;
use warnings;

# declare variable
my $section;

# run through every line
while (<>) {
  # set the current section to 'gene', 'CDS' or 'mRNA' when it matches
  $section = $1 if /^\h*(gene|CDS|mRNA)/;

  # print if the current section is not 'gene'
  print if $section ne 'gene';
}
```

Comment: a welcomed addition,  the code is clean and readable too, you get +1 from me

Comment: @OlivierDulac Glad you like it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed-program to delete a block of lines from a file, where each block begins with a line of a specific pattern and ends where the next block starts. (I could call this kind of blocks *sections*, and the task would be to delete a section with sed.)

Let's start with an obvious attempt to solve this (similar to the suggestion from the comment by @Stéphane-Chazelas), which however won't work:

```bsh
sed '/^     gene/,/^     [^ ]/ d'
```

Our section ends and the next section begins when there are 5 spaces at the beginning of the line followed by a non-space. Our section begins with 5 spaces and `gene`.

The problem with this simple sed-program is that the address range matches also the beginning line of the next section and deletes it, too.

But this works:

```bsh
end='^     [^ ]'
begin='^     gene'
sed --regexp-extended -e "/$begin/,/$end/ {
        /$end/! d # skip the end, otherwise delete
        /$begin/ d # do not skip (even if it happens to match end)
    }" \
    -i -- "$@"
```

Trying it on your example gives the wanted result:

```
$ cp example-stackexchange-360117.txt{.orig,} -vf
'example-stackexchange-360117.txt.orig' -> 'example-stackexchange-360117.txt'
$ ./delete-section2-gene example-stackexchange-360117.txt
$ diff example-stackexchange-360117.txt{.orig,}
1,3d0
<      gene            3025..3855
<                      /gene="Sp34_10000100"
<                      /ID="Sp34_10000100"
11,13d7
<      gene            12640..13470
<                      /gene="Sp34_10000200"
<                      /ID="Sp34_10000200"
21,23d14
<      gene            15959..20678
<                      /gene="Sp34_10000300"
<                      /ID="Sp34_10000300"
31,33d21
<      gene            22255..23085
<                      /gene="Sp34_10000400"
<                      /ID="Sp34_10000400"
$
```

Note that it even magically deleted the final section at the end of file, although there is no following line which would match `$end`! (The reason is not clear to me from the GNU sed manual.)

I've had a similar problem, for which I've made up this solution: delete a whole function definition from a Python source, namely from [Lib/test/audit-tests.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/test/audit-tests.py) from Python 3.8.1 sources.

I used the same script with different patterns:

```bsh
end='^[^[:blank:]]'
begin='^def .*winreg'
sed --regexp-extended -e "/$begin/,/$end/ {
        /$end/! d # skip the end, otherwise delete
        /$begin/ d # do not skip (even if it happens to match end)
    }" \
    -i -- "$@"
```

and it worked well deleting exactly one function definition, which ends where the indentation is again the toplevel one (i.e., the next section begins at zero indentation):

```
$ git checkout 3.8
$ ../delete-section2 Lib/test/audit-tests.py 
$ git --no-pager diff
diff --git a/Lib/test/audit-tests.py b/Lib/test/audit-tests.py
index 33f320992b..ed08612c04 100644
--- a/Lib/test/audit-tests.py
+++ b/Lib/test/audit-tests.py
@@ -304,29 +304,6 @@ def test_unraisablehook():
     write_unraisable_exc(RuntimeError("nonfatal-error"), "for audit hook test", None)


-def test_winreg():
-    from winreg import OpenKey, EnumKey, CloseKey, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
-
-    def hook(event, args):
-        if not event.startswith("winreg."):
-            return
-        print(event, *args)
-
-    sys.addaudithook(hook)
-
-    k = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software")
-    EnumKey(k, 0)
-    try:
-        EnumKey(k, 10000)
-    except OSError:
-        pass
-    else:
-        raise RuntimeError("Expected EnumKey(HKLM, 10000) to fail")
-
-    kv = k.Detach()
-    CloseKey(kv)
-
-
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     from test.libregrtest.setup import suppress_msvcrt_asserts

$
```

A variation of this sed-program with the `b` command ("branch"):

```bsh
end='^[^[:blank:]]'
begin='^def .*winreg'
sed --regexp-extended -e "/$begin/,/$end/ {
        /$begin/ d # delete, do not skip
        /$end/ b # skip
        d # default action
    }" \
    -i -- "$@"
```